# Call a function of base class casted to derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Say that I have the following code, is it safe to use?

Base class:

```
class B
{
    public:
    B(bool isDerived = false) : m_isDerived(isDerived) {}
    bool isDerived() { return m_isDerived; }

    private:
    bool m_isDerived;
}
```

Derived class:

```
class D : public B
{
    public:
    D() : B(true) {}
}
```

Code:

```
B* b = new B(); // Create new base class
D* unknown = static_cast<D*>(b); // Cast the base class into a derived class

if (unknown->isDerived()) // Is this allowed?
    // unknown is a D and can be used as such
else
    // unknown is not a D and can not be used
```

Can I safely call unknown->isDerived() even though unknown is really a B in this case?

We make the assumption that unknown NEVER contains anything other than a B* or D* and that we NEVER do anything with unknown until isDerived() have been checked on it.

**Edit**:

*Given the questions I will try to explain the reason why I'm trying to do this:
So essentially I have a Windows tree control which of course can't be directly connected to the c++ tree structure I'm using to store my data. So I have to reinterpret_cast my data to a DWORD_PTR that is stored together with each node in the tree control so I have a connection between the two. My tree structure consists of either the base type (a normal node) or the derived type (a node with more info in it that should be handled differently). The pointers to these are reinterpret_cast:ed and put in the tree control.*

*Now, when I'm stepping through the tree control I want to act on the nodes which are of the derived type, so I want to reinterpret_cast the DWORD_PTR into a derived type. But to be entirely correct I should reinterpret_cast it to a base type first (I guess?), and then downcast it to the derived type if it is a derived type. However I thought I could make it a bit simpler by reinterpret_cast it into a derived type immediately and then check via the function if it really is a derived type. If it wasn't I do nothing more with it. In my mind the base class data in the pointer should be at the same memory location no matter how much derived it is, but I might be wrong which is why I ask here.*

I wanted to make the question clearer by not involving Windows in it, but what I want in reality would be something closer to this:

```
B* b1 = new B();
B* b2 = new D();
DWORD_PTR ptr1 = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(b1);
DWORD_PTR ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(b2);

D* unknown = reinterpret_cast<D*>(ptr1 /* or ptr2 */); // Safe?
unknown->isDerived(); // Safe?
```

Essentially no matter what I do it's still unsafe at some level as I must reinterpret_cast the data.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `reinterpret_cast` to cast unrelated types?

Comment: @cppcoder That's a forced downcast and will likely trigger undefined behavior

Comment: have you tried compiling and see what it does?

Comment: @Iosif Murariu I have compiled and run it, as far as I can tell it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @DaedalusAlpha I suggest you to change the memory layout of the two classes as in my example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24201092/1938163 .

Comment: Absolutely not safe *or* sane to use at all. Don't.

Comment: It's also really hard to give a good answer because this is a classic XY problem. If I took your approach as intended literally, I would recommend a standard-layout union with a common initial sequence. But since you are in fact reinventing dynamic polymorphism, I think the correct advice is that you should stop trying to reinvent C++, which has already been invented, and instead *use* C++.

Comment: I'm deleting my answer: I don't get OP's point. Someone else will have better luck.

Comment: You can *possibly* use the rule that standard-layout class objects may be treated like their first data member, but it's tricky to get something to be standard layout, and you have no diagnostics if you get it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I safely call unknown->isDerived() even though unknown is really a
>   B in this case?

First of all, why would you do this? You could just call `b->isDerived()` and then do the downcasting.

Now, while premature and likely invalid downcast yields an undefined behavior (and should be universally despised) in this case it should work. Neither B nor D have implicit data members that might change the relative offset of `m_isDerived` and the address of `isDerived` member function is constant.

So yeah, it *should* work. If *should* is good enough for you.

EDIT: You can place a few tests to make sure offsets are same:

```
#include <cstddef> // for offsetof macro
#include <cassert> // for assert

#define offsetofclass(base, derived) ((static_cast<base*>((derived*)8))-8)

class Test
{
public:
    Test()
    {
        assert(offsetofclass(B, D) == 0);

        // you'll need to befriend Test with B & D to make this work
        // or make the filed public... or just move these asserts
        // to D's constructor
        assert(offsetof(B, m_isDerived) == offsetof(D, m_isDerived));
    }
};
Test g_test;
```

This will get executed on startup. I don't think it can be turned into a static assertion (executed and compile time).

Comment: Point out that derived contained some more members (which are not called before we know it's derived), could those change the offset of m_isDerived?

Comment: Unless `D` is virtual and `B` isn't or `D` derives from other types before deriving from `B`, it should stay same. Editing my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I think they all have merit, but I have to choose one so I'll pick this.

Answer (score 1):

Given your

```
class D : public B
```

and

```
B* b = new B(); // Create new base class
D* unknown = static_cast<D*>(b);
```

Formally this is Undefined Behavior, but, as long as only `B` things are accessed there's no technical reason why it should not work. Typically it's done in order to gain access to otherwise inaccessible `B` things, such as `std::stack<T>::c`. However there are better ways to do that, including the member function pointer trick.

---

Regarding

```
B(bool isDerived = false) : m_isDerived(isDerived) {}
```

that's very brittle and unsafe.

Instead class `B` should have a virtual member. Then you can use `dynamic_cast` and `typeid`. This is commonly known as **RTTI**, *Run-time Type Information*.

However, on the third and gripping hand, the relevant functionality should be made available via class `B` so that no downcasting is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

As you have pointed out yourself, the only generally correct approach for storing an arbitary hierarchy in a single, opaque pointer is to go via the base class. So, first make your hierarchy:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base(){}; /* ... */ };

struct FooDerived : Base       { /* ... */ };
struct BarDerived : Base       { /* ... */ };
struct ZipDerived : Base       { /* ... */ };
```

You will now exclusively transform between a `Base*` and whatever raw pointer type you have. Strictly speaking, you can only store pointers in either a `void*` or a `uintptr_t`, but let's assume that your `DWORD_PTR` is wide enough.

If we wrap everything in a function, the upcasting is already taken care of:

```
void marshal_pointer(Base const * p, DWORD_PTR & dst)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(DWORD_PTR) == sizeof(void *), "Not implementable");
    dst = reinterpret_cast<DWORD_PTR>(p);
}
```

The return direction is just as easy:

```
Base * unmarshal_pointer(DWORD_PTR src)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(DWORD_PTR) == sizeof(void *), "Not implementable");
    return reinterpret_cast<Base *>(src);
}
```

All the actual polymorphic behaviour should be implemented in terms of virtual functions if possible. Manual `dynamic_cast`s should be your last resort (though occasionally they're appropriate):

```
Base * p = unmarshal_pointer(weird_native_windows_thing);
p->TakeVirtualAction();
```